Issue in fitting Vertical and Horizontal bar in gantt chart
Not able to customise the Practice date and event date. The following case should be fit in the chart,

Case 1: Horizontal bar denotes the duration of the Practice session. Where it should have a break on holidays and sunday.
Case 2 : Verical Bar denotes the Event date for the specific practice session. Not all the event will have practice session, so the even might have session 1,4,5 also for a event.
Case 3: Red Line Indicate the leave or holiday that occurred during that time frame.

Expected Output

Trying different methods to get the vertical bar filled based on the specific practice session entered for that event. Any help on solving this issue is much appericiated.
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, calendar}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\geometry{top=1.8cm,bottom=2.3cm,left=0.5cm,right=0.5cm}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\definecolor{colorMagenta}{RGB}{255,0,255} %

\newcommand{\ganttcharttable}[9]{
    \newtoks \days
    \days{}    
    \def \titledimension{#2} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro \titleheight{{\titledimension}[0]}
    \pgfmathsetmacro \titlewidth{{\titledimension}[1]}
    
    \def \startdate{#5}
    \def \enddate{#6}
    \def \leavecount{#8}
    \def \leavedays{{#9}}

    \def \fontset{\footnotesize} 
    \def\pgfcalendarweekdayletter##1{%
        \fontset\tiny%       
        \ifcase##1Mon \or Tue \or Wed \or Thr \or Fri \or Sat \or \textcolor{red}{Sun}\fi%
    }

    \makeatletter
    \ganttset{
        conceptName/.code={
            \pgfqkeysalso{/pgfgantt}{@conceptName={##1}} },
        @conceptName/.code args={##1}{
            \pgfqkeysalso{/pgfgantt}{progress={100},progress label text={##1}}}
    }
    \makeatother  
    
    \foreach \i in {0,...,\inteval{\leavecount - 1}} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro \leaveday{\leavedays[\i][0]}
        \pgfmathsetmacro \leavedayname{\leavedays[\i][1]}
        \global\days\expandafter{%
            \expanded{%
                \the\days \noexpand\verticalrule{\leaveday}{\leavedayname}}}
    }

  \begin{ganttchart}[
        canvas/.append style={fill=none, draw=black!100, line width=1pt},
        title label font=\bfseries\footnotesize,  
        title height=#1,
        bar label font=\footnotesize\color{black!70},   
        inline, 
        bar inline label node/.style={font=\tiny,color=white,},
        bar/.append style={draw=none, fill=#4},
        group left shift=0,
        group right shift=0,
        group height=.5,  
        group peaks tip position=0, 
        group progress label font=\bfseries\small,
        link/.style={-latex, line width=1.5pt, black},
        time slot format=isodate,
        x unit=\titlewidth mm,
        y unit title=\titleheight mm, 
         vrule/.append style={red!75, thin},
         vrule label node/.style={ anchor=north,font=\fontset,rotate=90,xshift=-16,yshift=-2 },
        progress label text={}, 
        bar progress label font=\fontset\small,
        labelposLeft/.style={
            bar progress label node/.append style={anchor=west,left=4pt}, 
            bar progress label anchor=west,
        }  
    ]{\startdate}{\enddate}
        \gantttitlecalendar{month=name,day,weekday=letter, } \\    #7

        \the\days
    \end{ganttchart}
    
    \renewcommand{\days}{{ }}
}
\newcommand{\verticalrule}[2]{
    \ganttvrule{}{#1}
    \ganttvrule[vrule offset=-0.002]{#2}{#1}
}


\newcommand{\drawmarker}[6]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \draw[green!50,line width=18pt] (#1,#3) -- (#2,#4); 
        \node[anchor=west, black, font=\bfseries\normalsize, rotate=90] at (#2,#4-#5) {#6};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}


\begin{document}
    \drawmarker{5.4}{5.4}{-2}{-4.5}{7}{Event 1}  
    \drawmarker{9.9}{9.9}{-2}{-3.5}{8}{Event 2}
    \drawmarker{9.7}{9.7}{-6.5}{-5}{8.5}{}
    \drawmarker{15.3}{15.3}{-2}{-9.6}{2.8}{Match Day} 

    \begin{ganttcharttable}
        {0.9}                  
        {9,7}                  
        {0.6}                  
        {colorMagenta}         
        {2024-06-20}           
        {2024-07-10}           
        {                      
        \ganttbar[conceptName=Foot Ball Practice 1]{2 days}{2024-06-20}{2024-06-21} \\
        \ganttbar[conceptName=Foot Ball Practice 2, labelposLeft]{2 days}{2024-06-22}{2024-06-23} \\
        \ganttbar[conceptName=Foot Ball Practice 3]{5 day}{2024-06-23}{2024-06-27} \\
        \ganttbar[conceptName=Foot BallPractice 4]{2 days}{2024-06-28}{2024-06-29} \\
        \ganttbar[conceptName=Foot Ball Practice 5]{3 days}{2024-07-01}{2024-07-03} \\
        \ganttbar[conceptName=Foot Ball Practice 6,labelposLeft]{1 days}{2024-07-04}{2024-07-04} 
        \ganttbar[]{2 Days}{2024-07-06}{2024-07-06}\\
        \ganttbar[conceptName=Foot Ball Practice 6]{4 days}{2024-07-06}{2024-07-09}
        }
        {4}                     
        {                      
            {"2024-06-23", "Sunday"},
            {"2024-06-30", "Sunday"},
            {"2024-07-05", "Public Holiday"},
            {"2024-07-07", "Sunday"}
        }

    \end{ganttcharttable}
\end{document}```

